# Self-inflicted killing utility

Tags: java, multithreading, io, exception

If you need to kill the same process that you're in (for testing purposes or whatever) this code will do it.

A definitive, quick, unmerciful dead of the current Java program/app.
Not a System.exit(0) or a graceful dead.

A headshot to the running JVM

```
public class KillMe {

  private static final String CMD_WINDOWS = "taskkill /F /PID %d";
  private static final String CMD_LINUX = "kill -9 %d";

  public static void tryNow()  {
    Thread t = new Thread( () -> {
        try {
            now();
        } catch (CantKillMeException e) {
            //TODO whatever
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    t.setName("killmethread");
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
  }


public static void now() throws CantKillMeException {
    int pid = obtainPid();
    String command = getCommand(pid);
    executeCommand(command);
}

static int obtainPid() throws CantKillMeException {
    try {
        java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean runtime = java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
        java.lang.reflect.Field jvm = runtime.getClass().getDeclaredField("jvm");
        jvm.setAccessible(true);
        sun.management.VMManagement mgmt = (sun.management.VMManagement) jvm.get(runtime);
        java.lang.reflect.Method pid_method = mgmt.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getProcessId");
        pid_method.setAccessible(true);
        int pid = (Integer) pid_method.invoke(mgmt);
        return pid;
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new CantKillMeException("Cant obtain pid", e);
    }
}



// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573696/kill-a-process-based-on-pid-in-java
static String getCommand(int pid) {
    String command =  isWindows() ? CMD_WINDOWS : CMD_LINUX;
    return String.format(command,pid);
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288185/detecting-windows-or-linux
static boolean isWindows() {
    String osname = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    return osname.contains("win");
}

static void executeCommand(String command) throws CantKillMeException {
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (java.io.IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        throw new CantKillMeException("Cant execute command " + command, e);
    }
}


  public static class CantKillMeException extends Exception {

      CantKillMeException(String message, Throwable cause) {
          super(message, cause);
      }
  }

  }
```

Will work on Linux. Windows should work (not tested). There's room for improvement, for sure.

Comment: Indentation is a bit off, is it a copy paste issue?

Comment: What exactly do you want reviewed?

Answer (score 7):

Interesting little plot twist in a Java program.

First up, `tryNow()` is dead code, it's not used, get rid of it, it makes the rest of the class harder to understand by putting red-herrings in the code.

If it is really used somewhere else in your code (it is `public static`), then it should be moved out of this class in to a more usefully named location.... and it has other issues too, which I will ignore... except for .... never extend `Thread` directly, use `Runnable` ....

Next up, you should ensure you are using Java 9.x or newer, and then use the more [convenient `ProcessHandle` API for getting your current processID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html#current--)

This reduces the code:

> ```
> static int obtainPid() throws CantKillMeException {
>     try {
>         java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean runtime = java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
>         java.lang.reflect.Field jvm = runtime.getClass().getDeclaredField("jvm");
>         jvm.setAccessible(true);
>         sun.management.VMManagement mgmt = (sun.management.VMManagement) jvm.get(runtime);
>         java.lang.reflect.Method pid_method = mgmt.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getProcessId");
>         pid_method.setAccessible(true);
>         int pid = (Integer) pid_method.invoke(mgmt);
>         return pid;
>     } catch (IllegalAccessException | java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException |
> NoSuchFieldException e) {
>         throw new CantKillMeException("Cant obtain pid", e);
>     }
> }
> ```

to just:

```
static int obtainPid() throws CantKillMeException {
    try {
       return ProcessHandle.current().pid();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        throw new CantKillMeException("Cant obtain pid", e);
    }
}
```

Although you don't want to do a `System.exit(0)` I would still plan it as a backup...

You have

> ```
> static void executeCommand(String command) throws CantKillMeException {
>     try {
>         Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
>         process.waitFor();
>     } catch (java.io.IOException | InterruptedException e) {
>         throw new CantKillMeException("Cant execute command " + command, e);
>     }
>   }
> ```

which anticipates exceptions on something that should terminate the process....

I would instead log the exception (actually, catch any Throwable), and exit.... within a finally-block - I would do that in the `now()` method:

```
public static void now() throws CantKillMeException {
    try {
        int pid = obtainPid();
        String command = getCommand(pid);
        executeCommand(command);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        System.out.println(t);
    } finally {
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

You can choose a different (improved) logging mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to rolfl's answer:

there should be a check for a signal handler: make sure there isn't one or, if there's one, that it exits the application.

Comment: He kills using SIGKILL which can't be ignored or intercepted by a signal handler. SIGKILL is always deadly.